# please help me with xampp ,windows 7

Tags: php, xampp

9:44:43 AM  [Apache]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application

9:44:43 AM  [Apache]    or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port

9:44:43 AM  [Apache]    Problem detected!

9:44:43 AM  [Apache]    Port 443 in use by ""C:\Users\user\Desktop\xampp\apache
\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice" with PID 2628!

9:44:43 AM  [Apache]    Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!

9:44:43 AM  [Apache]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application

9:44:43 AM  [Apache]    or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port

9:44:43 AM  [Apache]    Attempting to start Apache service...

Comment: Probably ports are conflicting

Comment: http://complete-concrete-concise.com/web-tools/how-to-change-the-apache-port-in-xampp

Answer (score 0):

it looks like there is another program that is already bound to the ports that XAMPP is trying to bound too, you need to try to figure out what program(s) are using the ports and terminate them, it could also be the XAMPP is already running in the background...

edit: apache is already running... open task manager, and kill httpd.exe and then start it back up and it should work fine.

Comment: why do we to terminate existing program on a port cant we start or install xampp on other port?

Comment: yes.. but if he is wanting to use that for websites.. then port 80 is pretty much the only one that will work properly.. if he is just doing it for local only, then changing the port will have a small affect.. and by the looks of it, it looks like Apache is already started...

Comment: Because Apache accepts HTTP requests via Port 80, and HTTPS requested via Port 443.